# Angular 5 HttpClient returning before having the value

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, angular5

I'm starting to work with Angular and I have a pretty simple question.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/ngx-rocket/starter-kit) starter project that I created via the ngx-rocket tool, and I'm trying to implement the authentication using my webapi. I'm talking about this service ([see original code](https://github.com/ngx-rocket/starter-kit/blob/master/src/app/core/authentication/authentication.service.ts)).

As Http module I'm using the new one (`import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`). and I changed the `login` method of the service above to this:

```
  login(context: LoginContext): Observable<Credentials> {

    return  this._http.post<Credentials>("/api/account/login", 
      {Email : context.username,Password:context.password});        
  }
```

The http request happens and returns successfully. My problem: as you can see I should also set the credentials using `this.setCredentials(data, context.remember);`. What is confusing to me is how to return the observable and set the credentials in the same method? I tried keeping the returned observable in a variable, subscribing to it, setting the data and then return but it returns before setting the data (I know it's async).

This is what is confusing to me, it's pretty basic for Angular but still confusing to me. How can I change this method to give the proper return and also set the credentials?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `pipe`

```
login(context: LoginContext): Observable<Credentials> {
    return this._http.post<Credentials>("/api/account/login", {Email : context.username,Password:context.password})
                .pipe(
                    tap(data => {
                        this.setCredentials(data, context.remember);
                    })
                );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! TS is giving me: cannot find name 'tap'.  What should I import to have it?

Comment: `import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the lettable [tap](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md) (*formerly `do`*) operator and still return the observable.

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators/tap';

login(context: LoginContext): Observable<Credentials> {
    return this._http.post<Credentials>("/api/account/login", {Email : context.username,Password:context.password})
        .pipe(do((response) => {
          // this.setCredentials(data, context.remember);
        })
    );
}
```

The operation is commented out because I am not sure what you are getting back or wanting to pass.

If you wanted to return something different based on the actions of `setCredentials` then use `map` instead and return something from the method.